# Check the language of numbers if it is English or Arabic/Persian

Tags: swift, unicode, persian, nslocale, farsi

In my project I am planning to change the language of any type number to Persian and here is what I have done:

```
public extension String {
    func perstianString (string: String)->String {
        let digitSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
        var finalString = String()
        for ch in string.unicodeScalars {
            if digitSet.contains(ch) {
                let sh = convertoPersianNum(num: "\(ch)")
                finalString += sh
                }
            } else {
                finalString += "\(ch)"
            }
        }
        return finalString
    }

    func convertoPersianNum(num: String)->String{
        var retVlue = String()
        var num1 = num

        let number = NSNumber(value: Int(num1)!)

        let numb = (num as NSString).intValue
        let format = NumberFormatter()
        format.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        let faNumber = format.string(from: number)

        return faNumber!
    }
}
```

But when the source value has Persian numbers, the app crashes. Simply said, I want to check if it is a Persian number, don't do anything, else do the the conversion above:

```
let string = "ییسس ۱۲۳۴"
```

with this type do not do anything else do something.

Answer (score 0):

```
public extension String {

    private var isPersian: Bool {

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "(?s).*\\p{Arabic}.*")
        return predicate.evaluate(with: self)
    }

    private var toPersianNum: String {

        let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: self)
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        return formatter.string(from: number) ?? ""
    }

    var persian:String {

        var retVal = String()

        self.enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..<endIndex, options: .byComposedCharacterSequences) { (string, _, _, _) in
            guard let string = string else {return}

            if string.isPersian {
                retVal += string
            }else {
                retVal += string.toPersianNum
            }
        }
        return retVal
    }
}


let string = "9001ییسس2345777 ۱۲۳۴2345"

string.persian // "۹۰۰۱ییسس۲۳۴۵۷۷۷ناعدد۱۲۳۴۲۳۴۵" (result)
```